# Windows 8 store app capture video/photo without the special UI

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, winjs

I'm wondering if there is a way to capture photos/videos without leaving our app (and get the message "is this application allowed to...").
I'd like to have the camera view directly in my app.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, take a look at the [`MediaCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) class. In fact, that's the only way of doing it in Windows Phone (8.1).

With that you can have a `video` element in one of your pages and stream directly what's being seen by the camera.

I recently pushed the first version of an example we're putting together on [codeShow()](https://github.com/codefoster/codeshow/blob/master/codeShow.JS/codeShow.JS.Shared/demos/still/still.js), take a look and feel free to fork and collaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as said below we can do it by create a video dom element then

```
        var init = function () {
            mediarec = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
            mediarec.
            mediarec.initializeAsync().done(initializeComplete, initializeError);
        };

        var initializeComplete = function (op) {
            startPreview();
        }

        function initializeError(op) {
            console.log(op.message);
        }

        var startPreview = function () {
            var myVideo = document.getElementById("my_camera");
            myVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediarec);
            myVideo.play();
        }

        init();
```